# Stanford NLP Sentiment - how to check if a word is recognized, is in the vocabulary?

Tags: dictionary, stanford-nlp, words, vocabulary

Is there a function that returns true if a word is recognized by Stanford NLP Sentiment and false if not?

For example, if I want to find the sentiment of the sentence: 
"I like AAA because of BBB." 
both the phrases (AAA) and (BBB) will not be recognized and therefore get the same phrase vector (which will effect the results).
I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `SentimentModel` instance, you can inspect its public member `wordVectors` (not sure why this is public, but I suppose that's a different story..).

```
SentimentModel model = SentimentModel.loadSerialized("edu/stanford/nlp/models/sentiment/sentiment.ser.gz");
boolean knownWord = model.wordVectors.containsKey("foo");
```

Comment: do you know who do I get the SentimentModel object given that I have a StanfordCoreNLP object that is supposed to contain it somehow?

Comment: As far as I can see in the code it's not possible to access the model instance directly from `StanfordCoreNLP` (member visibility issues). But you can instantiate your own `SentimentModel` with the default model configuration — see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
also it should be:
boolean knownWord = model.wordVectors.containsKey("foo");